# Did you mean: satellit altitud

Tags: support, search

Any ideas where this might be coming from?

> [image]

*No, why would you think such a thing you silly goose?*

Comment: I can reproduce this. satellit altitud returns 0 results as well, incidentally.

Comment: @DylanSp thanks! That means it wasn't just "cosmic rays" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature we're working on when there are typos or misspellings that produce zero results.  Obviously we're still testing this and tweaking as we go:

[Testing Search Feature - 'Did you mean'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303298/testing-search-feature-did-you-mean)

Comment: Thanks, if you have the option to add mipsellings manually, I'll nominate [amonia as the mipselled form of ammonia](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3944/27918).

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that for some reason it things you are trying to use a non-english language, using something about how your OS and/or browser is configured. Still, this is strange... It did not happen to me, but it did happen to at least two users that really doesn't make sense. I'm going to tag it as a bug.